# Issue with Decimal to Binary conversion using MIPSY

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I'm working on a project that will eventually allow a user to input a decimal number and it'll output either the Binary, Octal or Hexadecimal equivalent utilizing bitwise operators. Just working on Binary for now and currently it's not outputting anything. I'm having trouble pinpointing the issue.

```
        .data
binMem:
        # Allocate 33 bytes for buffer and null terminate the buffer
        .space 33
        .asciiz "" 
firstMenuLine:
        .asciiz "Select an output format: \n"

secondMenuLine:
        .asciiz "1. Binary \n"

thirdMenuLine:
        .asciiz "2. Octal \n"

fourthMenuLine:
        .asciiz "3. Hexadecimal \n"

fifthMenuLine:
        .asciiz "4. Exit \n"

firstPrompt:
        .asciiz "Enter your choice: "

secondPrompt:
        .asciiz "Enter a decimal number: "

binResult:
        .asciiz "Binary: "

octResult:
        .asciiz "Octal: "

hexResult:
        .asciiz "Hexadecimal: "
exit:
        .asciiz "Goodbye"
        .text

main:
        # Ouput the first line
        li      $v0, 4
        la      $a0, firstMenuLine
        syscall

        # Output the second line
        li      $v0, 4
        la      $a0, secondMenuLine
        syscall

        # Output the third line
        li      $v0, 4
        la      $a0, thirdMenuLine
        syscall

        # Output the fourth line
        li      $v0, 4
        la      $a0, fourthMenuLine
        syscall

        # Output the fifth line
        li      $v0, 4
        la      $a0, fifthMenuLine
        syscall

        # Output the first Prompt
        li      $v0, 4
        la      $a0, firstPrompt
        syscall

        # Input a menu select character and move it to $t0 or quit
        li      $v0, 12
        syscall
        move    $t0, $v0
        beq     $t0, '4', end

        # Output the second Prompt
        li      $v0, 4
        la      $a0, secondPrompt
        syscall

        # Input a decimal number for conversion, assign to $t1
        li      $v0, 5
        syscall
        move    $t1, $v0

convertLoop:

        # If $t0 is 1, jump to convertBin
        beq     $t0, '1', initBin

        # If $t0 is 2, jump to convertOct
        beq     $t0, '2', convertOct

        # If $t0 is 3, jump to convertHex
        beq     $t0, '3', convertHex

initBin:
        #Clear the buffer, and set counter to number of bits 

        la      $t3, binMem
        li      $t2, 32
        j       convertBin
        
convertBin:
        # Check if decimal number is not zero (all bits processed)
        beqz    $t2, convertBin
        
        # Decrement counter
        addi    $t2, $t2, -1

        # Extract the least significant binOutput
        andi    $t4, $t1, 1

        # Store bit in the buffer
        sb      $t4, ($t3)

        # Shift right by 1 (divide by 2)
        srl     $t1, $t1, 1

        # Move to the next buffer position
        addi    $t3, $t3, 1

        j       binOutput

convertOct:

convertHex:

binOutput:

        # Output the result
        li      $v0, 4          # printf("Result: ");
        la      $a0, binResult
        syscall

        # Output the number in $t2
        la      $a0, binMem
        li      $v0, 4          # printf("%s", binMem);
        syscall
        
        # Output newline char
        li      $v0, 11
        li      $a0, '\n'
        syscall
        
        j       main

end:
        #   Exit the Program and return 0
        li      $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I had previously set the counter in initBin to 1, but this was only outputting the first binary bit, regardless of the decimal number (though that bit was correct).

I've also tried allocating the amount of bytes in binMem to be exactly the same as the output, however this throws initialization error.

Comment: You need to study the difference between numeric data, and strings & characters.